# Does Laravel have support for mocking database calls so we don't have to test our database?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, mocking

In many frameworks like Springboot, mocking the database is common practice because it's an external resource and it can increase latency with testing.

I haven't seen that so far from Laravel. Is there an offering or documentation around mocking the database calls?

We have tried using some smaller libraries but they are volatile to change and we need an enterprise solution.

Comment: Short answer - no. You can implement a Repository layer and mock repositories, but i reccomend testing with database. Optimization in this - is pessimization.

Comment: @Maksim and sometimes can get very complex depending on what you want to mock from a Model, lots of internal executions that you could be removing from the DB layer, creating issues like attribute casting not working, or scopes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Laravel provides robust capabilities for testing.

If you're using `PHPUnit`, in **phpunit.xml**

```
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

Or with `RefreshDatabase`, read [Quick tip: How to set up in-memory database for Laravel unit tests](https://arter.dev/quick-tip-how-to-set-up-in-memory-database-for-laravel-unit-tests)

---

As well we have [**Mocking Facades**](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mocking#mocking-facades), [Mocking](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mocking)

```
DB::shouldReceive('table')
    ->once()
    ->with('products')
    ->andReturn(new class {
        public function get() {
            return collect([(object) ['id' => 1, 'code' => 'samsung']]);
        }
    });

$products = DB::table('products')->get();

$this->assertEquals(1, count($products));
```

Comment: what if you are using eloquent, can you mock that?

Comment: If you're using `PHPUnit` use an in-memory database. No issues you don't need to have database either

Comment: can you explain why I wouldn't need a database and what the benefits of an in memory database would be in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest to NOT mock any DB calls, why? Laravel has events, scopes, attributes, etc behind scenes (that you can set), and if you mock one method, maybe a scope is not applied, or anything else, so I always suggest NOT mocking the database.

It is easier to set up a clean test database and migrate it and when all the tests are done, do something with it, than mocking calls and whatever from either `DB` facade or a or more than one class extending `Model`.

You can check my profile, I do have some links in there related to other StackOverflow questions about testing, that may help you a lot in general.

---

Which one is easier for you (I am going to use [@Abdulla Nilam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4595675/abdulla-nilam)'s example):

```php
DB::shouldReceive('table')
    ->once()
    ->with('products')
    ->andReturn(new class {
        public function get() {
            return collect([(object) ['id' => 1, 'code' => 'samsung']]);
        }
    });

$products = DB::table('products')->get();

$this->assertEquals(1, count($products));
```

Or this more "laravel way" approach:

```php
// This call hypothetically creates a Product
$this->post('/your/url')
    ->assertCreated();

$this->assertNotEmpty(Product::all());
```

Of course, these are super simple examples, but 99.9% of the time do not mock database calls at all. You definitely can, but you are very prone to mock something that Laravel processes on the back, as I said before, maybe an event, a scope, an attribute casting, etc.